Creating HashMap of point(x,y) and ArrayList<Integer> in java
I have to make a HashMap of point and Array-list. point is nothing but the pair of x and y in x-y plain.
then i want to store all student's roll no. which are there at that specific point.
as we don't have pair in java, so for point, i created another class named pair, which has int x and int y two variable and also it has two methods to access x and y. and one constructor to initialize x and y.
Now the main problem is :
when i wanna add new point to the hash-map, i create a new object of pair class and push the roll no.
but problem is that, How can i check that any point is already existing in the HashMap or not.
when i use map.containsKey() i have to pass that pair but how i will pass that pair, to pass pair i will create another object and when i pass it to containsKey() function it don't detect the already existing (x,y) pair.and add the same (x,y) pair as new key in hashmap.

Implement the equal method of your point class?

You're facing a common issue in Java when using custom objects as keys in HashMaps. The problem is that by default, Java's Object class uses reference equality, not structural equality, when comparing objects. So, even if you create a new Pair object with the same x and y values, it won't be considered equal to an existing Pair object in the HashMap if it has a different memory address.
To solve this problem, you need to override the equals() and hashCode() methods in your Pair class so that they define equality based on the values of x and y rather than on the object's memory address. Here's how you can do it:
    import java.util.*;

class Pair {
    int x, y;
    
    public Pair(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    // Override equals() method to define equality based on values of x and y
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Pair pair = (Pair) o;
        return x == pair.x && y == pair.y;
    }

    // Override hashCode() method to ensure consistency with equals()
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(x, y);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Pair, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
        
        Pair point = new Pair(3, 4);
        ArrayList<Integer> rollNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        rollNumbers.add(101);
        map.put(point, rollNumbers);
        
        // Check if point already exists
        Pair newPoint = new Pair(3, 4);
        if (map.containsKey(newPoint)) {
            // Point already exists, update roll numbers or do something else
            System.out.println("Point already exists in the map.");
        } else {
            // Point doesn't exist, add it to the map
            ArrayList<Integer> newRollNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
            newRollNumbers.add(102);
            map.put(newPoint, newRollNumbers);
            System.out.println("New point added to the map.");
        }
    }
}


What's said in Proctor Kai's answer is correct, but you can simplify the task by creating a record Pair instead of a class Pair:
public record Pair( int x, int y ) {}

Jepp, that's all! It has the accessor methods x() and y(), and it has implementations for Object::equals and Object::hashCode that considers x and y – fits perfectly for the key of a HashMap.
Proctor Kai's sample code simplifies to this:
import java.util.*;
    
record Pair( int x, int y ) {}
    
public final class Main 
{
  public static final void main( String... args ) 
  {
    final HashMap<Pair,ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
            
    final var point = new Pair( 3, 4 );
    final ArrayList<Integer> rollNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    rollNumbers.add(101);
    map.put( point, rollNumbers );
            
    // Check if point already exists
    final var newPoint = new Pair( 3, 4 );
    if( map.containsKey( newPoint ) ) 
    {
      // Point already exists, update roll numbers or do something else
      System.out.println( "Point already exists in the map." );
    } 
    else 
    {
      // Point doesn't exist, add it to the map
      final ArrayList<Integer> newRollNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
      newRollNumbers.add( 102 );
      map.put( newPoint, newRollNumbers );
      System.out.println( "New point added to the map." );
    }
  }
}

Notice that the logic of the  Main class was not modified at all … just the formatting.
